# Remove white space above html div and center it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to remove the white strip above the "form-strip" div and also center it to the middle of the page (exactly below the image) with no success. Any suggestions? 
(I also used a CSS reset style).

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="he">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="Styles/Reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Styles/Base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body dir="rtl">
    <header>
        <div class="title">
            <h1>text come here</h1>
            <h2>text come here</h2>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="img-strip" align="center">
        <img src="img/picture.jpg" class="image" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-strip" align="center">
        <h1>text come here</h1>
                <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="">

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="text come here">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="text come here">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="text come here">
                    <input type="text" class="form-phone" id="phone" placeholder="text come here">

                    <ul>
                        <li>052</li>
                        <li>054</li>
                        <li>057</li>
                    </ul>

                    <input type="submit" value="text come here">

                </form>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" />

        <div class="address">
            <h1>text come here</h1>
            <h2>text come here</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS - base.css:

```
body{
    direction: rtl;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;

}

.title h1 {
    font-family:"FbSpoiler";
    font-size:18px;
    color:#1BABCD;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:lighter;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.title h2 {
    font-family:"FbSpoiler";
    font-size:22px;
    color:#1BABCD;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

img.image {
    max-width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}

.form-strip {
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-color:#016a88;
    height: 70px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 920px;
}

.form-strip h1 {
    font-family:"FbSpoiler";
    font-size:15px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight:lighter;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.form-control {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}

.form-phone {
    width: 150px; 
    height: 25px;
}

.footer {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 700px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height: 100px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 920px;
}


.address h1 {
    font-family:"FbSpoiler";
    font-size:10px;
    color:#737676;
    text-align:right;
    font-weight:lighter;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.address h2 {
    font-size:15px;
    color:#737676;
    text-align:right;
    font-weight:lighter;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: And a live demo or screenshot maybe?

Comment: It's stil a bit vague to me. Don't know exactly what you want.

Comment: to align the form-strip to the center you need to add:

    margin: 0 auto;

without a js fiddle i cant see a white strip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the image in the div above the form-strip div a block element to get rid of the gap.

```
div.img-strip img {
    display: block;
}
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to center - the div.form-strip? If so add left/right margins of 'auto' to it:

```
div.form-strip {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! this was very helpful. Can you please explain why I cant put "margin: 0 auto" just inside the .form-strip class selector?

I mean:

.form-strip {
margin: 0 auto
 padding-top: 10px;
 background-color:#016a88;
 height: 70px;
 clear: both;
 overflow: hidden;
 max-width: 920px;
}

Comment: Yes you can insert it into your existing selector, I just wrote the above without the existing css properties for clarity.  Did applying display: block to the image remove the gap?

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.form-strip {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;

}
```